# Xamarin HttpClient GetStringAsync never return

Tags: rest, xamarin, httpclient

The following code never returns any value, I'm studying Xamarin Forms and I'm using Portable Class Library on VS2017, whenever I run the app it hangs on this line
 `var content = await _client.GetStringAsync (_url);`
 and never returns anything until the app throws an Exception (TaskCanceledException) I've searched Google all over and can not find any solution ...
 It does not work both on iOS and Android, I also tested on Shared instead of PCL and it also does not work. .. I installed Microsoft.Net.Http on all projects (PCL, Android and iOS)

I am a beginner and I am learning now to consume restful api

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Posts
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private const string _url ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(_url);
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);
        postsListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that your Device / Emulator has internet access?

Comment: I put the internet permission, I'm not using emulator and I tested it by accessing the url through the mobile browser

Comment: If you can access the end-point from the device browser, looks like you have to enable internet access for your application, using the manifest file: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: I already added the permission and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and testing, I discovered that the problem is the Json API returned to me. What I did not understand is that when I access the url through the browser, json comes right and in VS it did not take any error when parsing json